# NodeJS/ExpressJS Promises exception handling: catch v/s reject

Tags: node.js, express, exception, promise

I have an ExpressJS app in which I'm using ES6 Promises Polyfill.

I have read different things about handling Promise rejection in NodeJS. I have seen some folks following the

```
promise.then(function(response){}, function(error){next(error);})
```

Others recommend

```
promise.then(function(response){}).catch(next)
```

Yet others say

```
promise.then(function(response){}, function(error){next(error);}).catch(next)
```

I understand that in the first method handles asynchronous exception as rejections and don't handle synchronous exceptions.

The second one seems to consider any synchronous or asynchronous exception as a rejection.

The third one handles synchronous exceptions as is, and asynchronous exceptions as rejections. This seems to be the ideal solution to me.

Is this understanding correct? If not, what is the ideal way to handle this in Express?

Comment: The simple answer is no, your understanding is not correct. You are more likely to attract more helpful answers by asking a concrete question about and actual issue. As it stands, your subsidiary question asks "what is the ideal way to handle this in Express", but "this" is unstated.

Comment: In my question *this* is: "NodeJS/ExpressJS Promises exception handling: catch v/s reject". I mean to ask what the ideal way is to handle promise rejection handling in Express